# How to join 2 or more sculpts into one?

Tags: mesh, sculpting

I want to join these sculpts (and many others), into one single mesh.
Everytime i try to sculpt these 2 joined with Ctrl+J, i got an horrible middle empty space, also it looks cutted.

So, how i can join these two sculpts and then sculpt them like it was only one and not 2 apart?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use the Boolean Modifier. Or if you want to have a better workflow use the BoolTool addon. Tutorials on how to use them are enough out there and its quite simple but I will explain it nevertheless.

1. Add the Boolean Modifier to the first object you want to merge.
2. Click that little eyedropper in the object box of that modifier.
3. hover over the object to merge with and press <kbd>LMB</kbd>
4. Apply the modifier and delete the mesh that you selected with the eyedropper

All of that can be done with the BoolTool addon with one click on the Direct Union button

Comment: I tried the BoolTool, but the part that connect with the toes dissapear when using the direct union, idk why.

Comment: thats often due to selfintersecting or non manifold meshes. You can check if its not manifold by deselecting everything in editmode press space an type in manifold press enter and check the selected vertices count in the infobar at the top

Answer (score 0):

Automatic tools aren't well suited to joining those meshes, because the surfaces are ill-aligned. But there are a couple of things you can do to improve the result.

Firstly, it would make things easier if, assuming they have a non-subdivided form, the adjacent loops have the same or similar vertex counts. That way you could use ctrl+j as before and then join the loops in edit mode. For loop operations like that I recommend the Loop Tools addon.

It also looks as though these are non-manifold meshes. If you want to use Boolean modifiers I find its best to make both parts manifold. If the manifold meshes overlap they can be joined by the Boolean modifier, but you'll likely get rather messy joints that will need sculpting afterwards.

Finally, you could try replicating rather than joining. Make the centre mesh unselectable and then use it as a visual guide to help you sculpt the larger mesh so that it matches to your satisfaction.